# Как создать переменную в Yii2, работающую и в view и в layout?

Tags: yii2

Есть количество товаров в корзине.

Это количество отображается в шапке (layout), в меню для мобилки (layout) и на странице товаров, появляется кнопка прижатая к низу экрана (view).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в каждом случае идет отдельный вызов в базу данных, для поиска количества.
Как создать какую-то глобальную переменную с одной вылазкой в базу, чтобы можно было ее вызвать во всех трех местах?

Comment: есть два варианта: сделать банально виджет..........второй вариант - сделать пересчёт на js....

Comment: Так и то и другое все равно нужно вызывать там, где это нужно, и опять же, три запроса в базу данных...

Comment: Надо значит ещё тему кэширования почитать.... а если в модели внутри сохранить, то и кэширование даже не понадобится... если переменаня не пуста -взять оттуда

Comment: а откуда три запроса возьмутся при работе с js если данные должны быть одни на странице а js'ом  взять данные и дорисовать в нужные места?

Answer (score 0):

В общем всё просто:

- Вариант 1 - сделать один ajax запрос на серевер и далее с помощью *Javascript* нарисовать данные там, где необходимо. Хоть в сотне мест.
- Вариант 2 - суть сводится к сохранению знаний о корзине куда-либо и при следующем обращении к методу - брать данные оттуда. Где эти данные будут храниться - вариантов тоже много:

  - Куки/Сессия
  - Кэш (например файловый кэш)
  - Можно в модели. Сделать свойство `$cartData` или `$cartCount` или что вы ещё хотите. Сделать метод, который смотрит, если `$cardData === null` то делаем запрос в БД, а в ином случае - брать данные из свойства.

  Главное не забывать очистить невалидные данные в какой-либо необходимый момент